# loop in php function foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I try to get the result

> danny love to eat orange and banana and grapes

Is it possible to get it through the function foreach

my Sample Code

```
$var = array (" orange "," banana "," grapes ");
echo 'danny love to eat ';

//NOT THIS METHOD
// echo $var [0];
// echo ("and");
// echo $var [1];
// echo ("and");
// echo $var [2];

//Through this method
foreach ($var as $fruit) {
echo $fruit ;
echo ("and");
}
```

The result I get if i use foreach

> danny love to eat orange and banana and grapes and

What's wrong ? :(

Answer (score 4):

You're echoing 'and' one too many times. You don't want to echo 'and' if you're on the last element.

Try this instead.

```
$var = array (" orange "," banana "," grapes ");
echo 'danny love to eat ' .implode('and',$var);
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

@[bassxzero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959469/5827005)'s answer is a great (In fact, I would recommend doing it that way over this way), but I wanted to show another way you could do this if you wanted to use a foreach loop still if you wanted to.

```
$var = array ("orange","banana","grapes");
$string = 'danny love to eat ';

//Through this method
foreach ($var as $fruit) {
    $string .= $fruit. " and ";
}
$string = substr($string, 0, -5);
echo $string;
```

In my code, we are building a string that contains all the words that you want seperated by " and ". Then as soon as the loop is done, we use `substr()` to remove the very last " and " so that `$string` equals the string you were expecting.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be

```
$var = array (" orange "," banana "," grapes ");
$str = 'danny love to eat ';
$total = count($var); // counts your aray
foreach ($var as $fruit) {
    $total--; // decrements $total value
    $str .= $total < 1 ? $fruit : $fruit.' and '; //if $total is reduced to 0 your loop is on the last repeat, so dont print 'and' anymore
}
echo $str;
```

Anyway `implode` way is the most elegant here.

Comment: could also do $str .= $total === 0 ? $fruit : $fruit.' and ';